# Display zero as a real number

Tags: javascript

I set the numeric value to `0.0` by default. 
But if display it, it will display as `0`.
How can I display a value in the form `0.0` (the type must be number), but not translate into a string?
That is, this option `var durationNumber = '0.0';` does not suit me.

```js
var durationNumber = 0.0;
console.log(durationNumber)
```

Comment: you can't display `0..toFixed(1)` but that HAS to be a string ... who cares if it's a string when you "display" it though, how can you tell it's a string vs number

Comment: @JaromandaX Post it as an answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok, thanks.

Comment: @user12916796, you should explain why you need to use `0.0`, but not `0`. Does there have format check logic to verify it? If so, use `'0.0'` as string is the perfect way. Otherwise, you may not need to care about `0.0` or `0`.